# Can I center an auto-fill grid with pure CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to fill my page horizontally with as many blocks as possible and center the result.

I want the grid to be able to resize when the window becomes smaller:

```
wide window
xxx

small window
xx
x
```

Is this possible to achieve without javascript?

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 6px red;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To explain the desired centering visually:

Can the yellow highlighted area be evenly distributed on either side?
[image]

The desired box alignment:
[image]

Comment: What's that `center` CSS class supposed to be doing?

Comment: @ellitt that's where I figured the rules would go that can center the grid. Is that the wrong approach? I have tried making center a flexbox, but then the grid can no longer auto-fill.

Comment: Instead of using auto-fill, have you tried auto-fit? You could also add `justify-content: space-evenly;` to your grid class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## This only works in chrome for some reason.

---

Auto-fit and auto-fill needs a known width to calculate from, we can do that with `max-width:100%` instead of using `width` which will stretch it and prevent us from centering, and avoid fixed widths.

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 6px red;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  max-width: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

There is a quirk with this, if you start with a wide `viewport` then resize it to a smaller one, the grid won't be centerd because of `auto-fill`

Say you have 3 elements but the container can fit 4 with `auto-fill` it will create a forth column but we have no forth element so it will look unevenly spaced.

I suggest using `auto-fit`, which instead of creating the forth column it will split the space evenly on each side.

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 6px red;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
  max-width: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Now if you resize the window enough you'll see sometimes it's not evenly spaced  that's because of the relative unit on the max-width, it need to recalculate the width because it's based on the parent and parent's width which is based on the content.

we can trigger that recalculation using an animation.

***chrome specific solution***

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 6px red;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
  max-width: 100%;
  animation: recalc 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes recalc {
  to {
    max-width: 99.9%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To support at least FF and maybe some other browsers, use viewport units.

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 6px red;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect! When the grid becomes too small for all three boxes, say 1 pixel after the third box drops to the second row, is it possible to center that result?

Comment: I don't think i understand what you mean, also there's a bug with this method but it's not visible, i'll explain it later.

Comment: I added a picture to the question to better explain.

Comment: Essentially I'm hoping to be able to combine the resizing alignment behavior of your snippet and the centered behavior of shutupchigo's answer.

Comment: Updated, if something isn't clear be sure to tell me, it's really late and i'm half dizzy writing this answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I have tried to get this to work for hours.

Comment: @Jehy i did more testing on this, it only seem to work on chrome, if you want to support FF i don't think you have a choice other than js or a fixed width, or maybe viewport units which are a bit more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for warning me. I guess I'll have to use a bit of js.

Comment: @Jehy Yes it's not much you just copy the parent's width and apply it as max-width to the grid, then you won't need the extra calculation chrome does to center the grid properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with flexbox.

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 6px red;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .grid {
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
 }
 .box {
  width: 50%
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to retain the automatic resizing in the original such that a smaller window can have 2 boxes on the first row, 1 box on the second row?

Comment: Very close to what I'm trying to achieve. Is it possible for the last box to be aligned with the left edge of the grid when it drops to the second row?

Comment: @Jehy made the .box 50% in mobile. so that there's no white space to the right.

Comment: I added a picture to my question to explain. Is it possible to center the overall grid, as in your answer, but not center the box on the last row?

Comment: I added a second picture. I reloaded the page and re-ran the snippet, do I need to do something else to get your updated code?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can centre an auto-fill, left-aligned grid (and it works in Firefox).**

To do this, you just need `justify-content: center;` on the grid container, which would give you this:

[image]

A good example of this (and why it works) is on the [MDN docs page for justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Your example would look like this:

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 6px red;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  justify-content: center; /* <-- This is all you need to add */
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's worth noting though, that when you only have one row of boxes, they may not be centred, since the repeat function will create empty columns to fill the row, effectively left aligning the actual boxes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `grid` for this. Use `flex`:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0; font-size:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#ccc;
}
.box{  
  width:200px; height:150px; background-color:white; border:6px solid red;
}
.box:nth-child(2n+2) {
  background-color:blue;
}
.center,.grid{
  display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; height:100%;
}
.grid{
  min-width:600px; flex-wrap:wrap; align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='center'>
  <div class='grid'>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```